# Not able to resolve my domain name intermittently on iOS

Tags: ios, network, wifi, safari, dns

I am experiencing a strange behavior w.r.t DNS resolution when connected to certain WiFi networks. (only on iOS devices)

Issue is: Safari is able to resolve my domain name correctly but sometimes for almost 2 minutes it is not able to resolve and throws a page not found error. This happens say once in a couple of hours.

If I enter my ip address in Safari it works. At the same time the domain resolution works fine on android devices.

One Fix is: If i change the DNS settings from my ISP DNS to point to Google or OpenDNS or another popular DNS server the issue disappears. (but i can't use this solution for my usecase since i can't ask all my users to change their DNS settings).

The Android device is also in the same network and points to my ISP DNS, but for some reason with android the issue does not exist.

It seems to be problem between Safari/iOS and my ISP DNS servers. Has someone faced a similar issue? Anything i can tryout?

P.S. I am using AWS instance and Route53 for DNS Service.

Comment: I would love to have more logging of DNS timing - I think you have listed one of the main pain points for iOS for me. Inconsistent performance and when you change things, it's hard to measure if you've made things worse or better or if the problem is just intermittent when the value isn't cached in the local cache.

Comment: @bmike Thanks for the response, how can i log DNS timing. Is there any way i can do that and get that to you? If the problem is known can there be a resolution to this without touching the DNS settings. I have started doubting that even if i know the issue i would have to live with it, since the only fix i can do is to my application code.

Comment: Sorry - I would love it if Apple implemented more logging. It's a black box AFAIK.